# Python - When duplicate items are identified, which object does a set or frozenset take?

Tags: python, hash, set

I have a user-defined class `MyClass` that has a `__hash__` and `__eq__` implementation that ensures that, for example:

```
>>> a = MyClass([100, 99, 98, 97])
>>> b = MyClass([99, 98, 97, 100])
>>> a.__hash__() == b.__hash__()
True
>>> a == b
True
```

Question: if I do the following:

```
>>> x = [a, b]
>>> set(x)
```

can I count on `set` keeping `a`? Is the set `__init__` iterating through `x` in order? Or do I need to worry about it taking `b` randomly?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these cases of hash-based things, it uses both `__hash__` and `__eq__`.

If `__hash__` and `__eq__` are both the same, then the first one it gets to in the iterable is taken. When it gets to the next, it checks if it already has it and decides yes.

```
>>> class Same(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return 42
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return True
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'Same(%r)' % self.value
>>> set([Same(2), Same(1)])
set([Same(2)])
>>> set([Same(1), Same(2)])
set([Same(1)])
```

With a `dict`, it becomes more interesting:

```
>>> {Same(1): 1, Same(2): 2}
{Same(1): 2}
>>> {Same(1): 2, Same(2): 1}
{Same(1): 1}
>>> {Same(2): 1, Same(2): 2}
{Same(2): 2}
>>> {Same(2): 2, Same(2): 1}
{Same(2): 1}
>>> {Same(2): 2, Same(2): 1}
{Same(2): 1}
```

You should be able to guess what's happening here. It stores the first item, then the hash/equality of the second is the same; however, it's got a different value, so it stores that. The *value* is overwritten always, whether they match or not:

```
>>> {Same(1): Same(2), Same(3): Same(4)}
{Same(1): Same(4)}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Clear, I think. Should the Some() be Same()? Not sure why the dictionary would return a different key class than the object I passed in.

Comment: bonus points for the 42 hash, because when you get right down to it, 42 is the hash for everything.

Comment: Sorry, when I'd typed it in the interactive console I'd mistyped the __repr__ as Some and forgot to correct it all when doing the dict stuff. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

`set` (and `dict`) check not only the equality of the hashes, but also the equality of the objects themselves into account.

Comment: It was more a question about the order of the set identification. Was trying to show the example so that people understood what I was trying to do.

Comment: Fair enough. But it still depends on more than just the hash.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but I didn't see anything on that in the Standard Library docs about the hash + eq needing to be overwritten. How do you all learn stuff like that? Do you have to look at the Python source itself?

Comment: @Mike: experiment!  That's what the interactive console is there for.

Comment: @MikeRand: You need to read between the lines of the langref. http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Answer (score 1):

I believe that set() requires both **hash** and **eq** to be overridden. In this case, you could have hash(a) == hash(b) but still have a != b, assuming you defined **eq** in such a fashion